# Obtain median value of this mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this array from a mysql interrogation:

```
 $listings = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT id, account_id
     FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ebay_auctions
     WHERE status = 'changed'
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT {$limit}", ARRAY_A );
```

But i need only middle value from this array, so value from 11 to 20, how can i mod this mysql query?

Comment: One way to do this is documented In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql#1895127.  See if that works for you.

Comment: if is more simple...for me is good to obtain from records 11 to 20 whitout middle...

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? Using prepared statements with placeholder values not only solves this problem but means you won’t spend hours chasing a tiny syntax bug due to incorrect escaping.

Comment: solved using OFFSET 20